# How to use interfaces from another file in typsecript to define DTO

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I'm trying to define interfaces in typescript that are DTOs, but when I import them I'm forced to implement them which is not what I want. I simply want to use the interface as a type. When I remove the implement keyword, I get this error:

**Error: TS2306 File 'templateJS.ts' is not a module**

How am I supposed to do this correctly?

templateJS.ts

```ts
export interface ITemplateJS {
  id: number,
  name: string
}
```

template.component.ts

```ts
import { ITemplateJS } from './../models/templateJS';
export class TemplateComponent {
    public template : ITemplateJS;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue happens when the file can't be found, so I would do something like. 
Instead of

```
import { ITemplateJS } from './../models/templateJS';
```

try

```
import { ITemplateJS } from '../models/templateJS';
```

I think that will solve your problem but a good practice is create a index.ts file and have all your interfaces/classes exported there and using that file you dont have to reference specific files.

Example:

1. Create `index.ts` file in your models folder.
2. Add this line to the index.ts file

   export * from './templateJS';

   // Add all the interfaces and classes that you want to export
3. Import your interface using:

   `import { ITemplateJS } from '../models';`

I hope this ideas help you solving this issue.

Happy coding!!!